# 'x' refresh is not a function. (In 'x()', 'x' is an instance of Object)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

How can I access to my refresh() method in my UpdateLokalListe function?
Is there any possibility to include the function in my class?

I used this guide: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen

Thanks

https://pastebin.com/NMfTS8tp

```
function UpdateLokalListe(refresh) {
useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
        refresh();
    })
);
return null;
}

export default class LokaleBearbeitenScreen extends Component {
state = {
    lokale: [],
    isLoading: true,
};

_retrieveData = async () => {
    ...
};

_refresh = () => {
    alert('refresh');
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    this._retrieveData();
};

componentDidMount() {
    Firebase.init();
    this._retrieveData();
}

render() {
    ...

    return (
        <>
            <UpdateLokalListe refresh={this._refresh} />

            ...
        </>
    );
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UpdateLokalListe` looks like functional component, and you are passing `refresh` props

So change this :

```
 UpdateLokalListe(refresh)
```

to :

```
 UpdateLokalListe({refresh})
```

---

**OR**

```
function UpdateLokalListe(props) { // <---- Here
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
        props.refresh(); // <---- Here
    })
  );
  return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks!
refresh updates my state so render is called and I got into a loop.. any idea?

Comment: that depends on `_retrieveData` or check `useFocusEffect`'s dependecy

Comment: `React.useCallback(() => {
        refresh();
    },[])` try this

Comment: still in loop. useFocusEffects gets fired again when I update my state in my retrieveData method